# Texlipse linked resource

Tags: texlipse

I'm trying to keep all my .tex macros in a single folder, so I don't have different versions of these macros.

Texlipse allows you to create a "linked resource" which mirrors a file outside the project folder. I can successfully link to a file, and I see the shortcut in the project window. However, when I try to build the project, Texlipse cannot locate the .tex file. Has anyone got this to work?

An alternative would be to store macros as .sty files in Miktex, but this would be difficult to sync across computers (I need to sync a work and home computer)

Mirroring a file from the command line is not a possibility as at work I'm on Windows without admin rights. Also, using LaTeX itself to locate the file outside the project folder (e.g. \input{../../../file.tex}) appears to be incompatible with Texlipse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as i know (and tested) using Linked Resources does not work with TeXlipse.

Instead, you might consider using the `import` package, which allows using absolute and relative paths to include files. It is also able to deal with server addresses (if you sync your files via a server) like `//srv01/files/tex`.

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{import}

\begin{document}

\import*{C:/}{test.tex}
\import*{../../../}{test.tex}

\end{document}
```

The first argument specifies the path, the second one the filename.

The `*` after the import command tells the `import` package not to search the TEXINPUTS path. If you use `import{...}`, MiKTeX will ask you every time whether you want to install the 'missing package' test.tex (or whatever you are importing).

For full documentation on the import package, see the [package's CTAN page](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/import).